# How to rotate a SVG marker via a data-defined override to the value of one field in a layer

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, svg

I have a pyqgis stand alone app that display linear features. I put an arrow svg symbol (`QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayerV2`) on the line, now I would like to rotate it based on the 'value' field of each line feature in the layer. I tried some variations to the suggested approach below, but they are not working:

```
sl = QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayerV2('arrow.svg')
lDD = QgsDataDefined(True, True, 'CASE WHEN "value" < 0 THEN 180.0 ELSE 0.0 END CASE', 'value')
sl.setDataDefinedProperty('angle', lDD)
```

Comment: If German's answer satisfies, please accept it so I can give the bounty.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding this line in your code snippet:

```
lDD = QgsDataDefined(True, True, 'CASE WHEN "value" < 0 THEN 180.0 ELSE 0.0 END CASE', 'value')
```

You need to close a `CASE` expression with `END` (i.e., `END CASE` is incorrect). Also, there is no need to pass the last parameter `'value'`, because you'll be using an expression and not a field.

---

If you want to **rotate an existing** SVG marker symbol layer based on a data defined expression, you can do this:

```
# This assumes your marker line symbol layer is the 2nd layer in the line symbol
ddProperty = QgsDataDefined( True, True, 
    'CASE WHEN "value" < 0 THEN 180.0 ELSE 0.0 END' )
iface.activeLayer().rendererV2().symbols()[0].symbolLayers()[1].subSymbol().setDataDefinedAngle( ddProperty )
iface.activeLayer().triggerRepaint()
```

---

If you want to **add a new SVG marker** layer on your lines, setting the angle of rotation based on data definition expression, use this:

```
# Create your SVG symbol layer setting the angle to an expression
svgSymLay = QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayerV2( 'arrows/Arrow_01.svg' )
ddProperty = QgsDataDefined( True, True, 
    'CASE WHEN "value" < 0 THEN 180.0 ELSE 0.0 END' ) 
svgSymLay.setDataDefinedProperty( 'angle', ddProperty )

# Create marker line symbol layer 
# and set a marker symbol (with the SVG layer) as sub-symbol
markerLineSymLay = QgsMarkerLineSymbolLayerV2()
markerSym = QgsMarkerSymbolV2()
markerSym.changeSymbolLayer( 0, svgSymLay )
markerLineSymLay.setSubSymbol( markerSym )

# Append the marker line symbol layer to a line symbol
lineSym = iface.activeLayer().rendererV2().symbols()[0]
lineSym.appendSymbolLayer( markerLineSymLay )

# Refresh layer and its symbology in the layer tree
iface.activeLayer().triggerRepaint()
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology( iface.activeLayer().id() )
```

---

**Note:** *As you're working on a standalone application, you wouldn't access layers nor layer tree via `iface`, but you should have ways to get layers and (optionally) layer tree in your application anyways.*

Comment: Gave you the bounty even before acceptance as OP seems AWOL. Thanks! :)