# Rotate SVG marker angle based on each feature's value

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I'm importing data, and creating a layer, which has a number of features, each with an `f_angle` attribute.

I'd like to create a data defined override to rotate the SVG marker by the angle defined by `f_angle` but am unsure how to do this using pyqgis in QGIS 3.

[This question/answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247116/how-to-rotate-a-svg-marker-via-a-data-defined-override-to-the-value-of-one-field) seems to show how to do it is QGIS 2, but `QgsDataDefined` has been [removed in QGIS 3](https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html#qgis_api_break_3_0_removed_classes) with the suggestion to use the `QgsProperty` framework instead.  However I'm struggling to find examples/documentation using that.

Can anyone tell me how to create a data defined override to rotate SVG markers based on a feature attribute in QGIS3, using pyqgis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QGIS 3.x API it looks like:

```
sl = QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayer('arrow.svg')
sl.dataDefinedProperties().setProperty(QgsSymbolLayer.PropertyAngle, QgsProperty.fromField('f_angle'))
```

Or, slightly shorter (But basically the same):

```
sl = QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayer('arrow.svg')
sl.setDataDefinedProperty(QgsSymbolLayer.PropertyAngle, QgsProperty.fromField('f_angle'))
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!  Given the time I wasted on this, I can't believe how simple the answer was.  Did you follow a documentation trail to get the answer (in which case I'd love to know what/how) or did you already know it?

Comment: Well, I have an advantage in that I wrote that part of the API, but the docs at https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.4/core/Symbol/QgsSymbolLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsSymbolLayer.setDataDefinedProperty and https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.4/core/Property/QgsProperty.html#qgis.core.QgsProperty.fromField . Hopefully they help!